# Conntecting to SQL Server by R on macOS

Tags: r, sql-server, macos

I have a problem to connect to my external sql server database on R. I am working on macOS. I tried to do everything as in tutorial: [LINK](https://db.rstudio.com/databases/microsoft-sql-server/#driver-options)

My code:

```
library(DBI) 
library(odbc) 
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver = "SQL Server", Server = "server", Database = "DataBaseName", UID = "Login", PWD = "password", Port = 1433)
```

but I still get this same error:

```
ERROR: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: 01000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I will be very grateful!